# Defining php class properties

Tags: php, class

I have a two simple questions but can't find the *right and correct* answer. How must I define my properties? Can I define in one line or not? Both works, but what is correct?

How do I define multiply properties with the same value?

```
class Page {
    private $value;
    public $title, $footer, $content; // like this?

    // or like this?
    public $title;
    public $footer
    public $content;        

    // multiply one line with the same value?
    public $name, $age, $place = "none";
    public $name = $age = $place = "none"; // error


    public function __construct($value) {
        $this->value = $value;
    }

    private function Header() {
        $q = "<!DOCTYPE html>\n";
        $q .= "<html>\n";
        $q .= "<head><title>".$this->title."</title></head>\n";
        $q .= "<body>\n\n";
        return $q;
    }

    private function Footer() {
        $q = "\n\n<div class=\"footer\">".$this->footer."</div>";
        $q .= "\n</body>\n</html>";
        return $q;
    }

    private function Content() {
        return $this->content;
    }

    public function DrawPage() {
        echo $this->Header();
        echo $this->Content();
        echo $this->Footer();
    }

    // for display only content in a jQuery ajax post
    public function DrawContent() {
        echo $this->Content();
    }

}

$page = new Page('/clean/url/item/5/page-title.html');
$page->header   = "my test page";
$page->footer   = "this is the footer text";
$page->content  = "Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text.";
$page->DrawPage();
```

Comment: [RTM](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.properties.php)

Comment: If both work then both are correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For something "quick and dirty", it's fine to use multiple definitions per line as long as you can understand it later.

For more formal code you should define one per line, especially if you are planning on writing [PHPDoc](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PHPDoc)'s at some point or if other people will be reading it.

With that said, it is always good practice to get used to doing it the "proper" way all the time.